# Can't install Ubuntu, getting error 'failed to load fecs_inst'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I am currently using windows 10 and created a bootable USB drive with universal USB. I used the ubuntu 16.04 iso and am getting the initial page that shows the Ubuntu logo then the screen cuts to a black screen.

The first line says `gr failed to load fecs inst` and there are about another 15 lines with memory addresses or something of the sort.

I tried this with 2 different USB and 2 different ports and had the same issue.

I am running a core i5 4590 with 8GB ram, 850 evo, GTX 970, and an additional 1TB hard drive. I've looked for this error but couldn't find any viable solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my mother board, an Asrock B85M-ITX is not compatible with Linux. That's the reason it would not boot or install.